# cv2.resize() function changes 16 bit grayscale to 24 bit grayscale

Tags: python, opencv

When enlarging or shrinking with the cv2.resize function, 16-bit grayscale images are increased to 24 bits. Is there a way to resize them without changing the depth?

```
img=cv2.imread("16bitgray.tiff")

img512 = cv2.resize(img, (512,512), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Comment: Are you sure the TIFF is 16-bit?  How do you save it to file?

Comment: @Tim Roberts I'm sure TIFF is 16-bit. `cv2.imwrite("img512 .tiff", img512 )` for saving file.

Comment: If you `print(img512.shape, img512.dtype)`, what do you see?  The OpenCV documentation says it writes 16-bit TIFFs.

Comment: (512, 512, 3) uint8

Comment: The "3" tells you this is not grayscale.  It's RGB.  Mark has the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read a 16-bit greyscale TIFF with:

```
img=cv2.imread("16bitgray.tiff")
```

you'll get an RGB888 TIFF because that is the default. You need:

```
img=cv2.imread("16bitgray.tiff", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```